# Loading numeric values incorrectly stored as text in to SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a `.csv` file that I have received from a third party - so am unable to sort the issue out at source. The `.csv` file is separated as follows:

```
"1","client_name","0","0"
"2","client_name","0","0"
```

I have successfully loaded the file into a staging table with all columns stored as `varchar(255)`. I am unable to convert column 4 to a `decimal(10,0)`. Which is the datatype of the live destination table.

Strangely enough column 3 and 4 contain only zeros, column 3 can be converted to `decimal(10,0)` but column 4 cannot.

```
ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(credit_terms, '"', ''))
```

Returns 0 for all rows in column 4, though 1 for all rows in column 3.

```
CAST(REPLACE(credit_terms, '"', '') AS DECIMAL(10,0))
```

Returns the error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

It is strange that what looks on the surface as an identical column (3) will covert fine, but 4 will not.

I fully understand that storing numbers as text is poor practice, but am unable to resolve this as the data originates from elsewhere.

Following suggestions I have now opened the file in a hex editor. At the end of each line is a line break that looks like this: .. (`Od & Oa`).

In the hex editor each row looks like this:

```
"1","client_name","0","0",..
"2","client_name","0","0",..
```

Comment: Is there any chance that the data is further corrupted in the spreadsheet? For example, is one of the zeros actually a letter "O"?  Or missing entirely?  Can you scan or validate the input?

Comment: Running select distinct REPLACE(credit_terms, '"', '') from ... order by 1 should reveal strange values

Comment: @JamesZ I did try something similar, this just returns 0.

Comment: Following on from @pmbAustin, is the file ASCII or any flavour of Unicode? If the latter then what looks like a zero could be a lot of different characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After advice from this question I found that the line break for the data was OA and OD.

0A is a line feed
0D is a carriage return

I was then able to replace char(10) - line feed and char(13) - carriage return as follows:

```
CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(credit_terms,char(10),''),CHAR(13),''),'"','') AS DECIMAL(10,0))
```

The column will now convert to a decimal as required. Thank you for all your pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that there isn't a hidden space " " character after the last 0; this can happen a lot in excel/csv files.  That would cause it to fail the conversion to numeric.
Also, make sure your index is correct.  Many things start at a 0 index so are you possibly trying to convert column[4], which relates to the 5th logical column?

Answer (score 0):

I HIGHLY recommend downloading a free trial of [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/), then opening it, open one of the above files, hit Ctrl-H to go into Hex mode which allows you to view the Hex / ASCII code of every character in a file (even the not visible ones), and eyeball whethere there is any characters that can't be seen that would cause the above conversion error.

I've seen this all the time with files generated by mainframes that add characters that hose up a subsequent import.

Also, since you have loaded it in SQL, do a quick SELECT LEN(Column4) to see if it returns anything other than 1.

Even better, do a SELECT Column4 FROM YourTable WHERE ISNUMERIC(Column4) = 0 to return a set with the offending values.

Comment: Thanks Jim, will have a look at it in hex. I think you're on to something as the len() of that column returns 2.

Comment: Also, if they are using SQL Server, there is a high probability they have Visual Studio as well. Visual Studio can open any file with a binary editor. I've used this on more than one occasion to search for bad input.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [TRY_CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx) to find values that won't convert;

```
select * from MyTable
where TRY_CAST(REPLACE(credit_terms, '"', '') AS DECIMAL(10,0)) is null
```

Comment: sadly I'm only on 2008 that doesn't feature the TRY_CAST function. Will update the tag.